# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication Cookie Problem

Tags: asp.net, cookies, internet-explorer-7

We use FormAuthentication to manage logins and I have a case where a customer complains where he can login from one computer but to from another.

I can see in my logs that his authentican is successfull but he gets bumped back to the login page. I can reproduce the symptons by disabling cookies so I asked the customer to test if cookies are enabled on http://www.tempesttech.com/cookies/cookietest1.asp, but this came out positive.

What have I missed? Is there any antivirus/security software that can mess up (ASP.NET) cookies?

The user is using IE7 and claims to have F-secure installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ask from your customer to try to **login using some other browser like google chrome**.

If with other browser works, **then ask from your customer to clear the cookies on his browser**, if he can clear only your page cookies, then you must be check if you using too much cookies, or too big ones, and create a diferent shecma.

**You maybe have set to store/cache the roles on cookie** - this make cookie too big ones, and big  cookies create problems.

Comment: I only set one cookie and that's a GUID (FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(client.Id.ToString(), true))

Comment: Ask from your client to clear your cookies, also ask him to use for test a different browser, and for be sure place on web.config roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="false".

Also after set the SetAuthCookies you must make a redirect (do you ?)